# How to set path for all users on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, path

I am working on server running on CENTOS 7.

I have compiled a few software from source code. I had executed **./configure**, **make**, **make install** as **SUPERUSER**.

To be accessible I need to set a PATH. I added the following lines in ~/.bashrc file as SU

> for adding PATH to HISAT2
>
> export PATH="/home/bioinformatics/Arindam/Software/Hisat2/hisat2-2.1.0/:$PATH"

As SUPERUSER it worked fine. But once I moved out of SU I was not able to do so.  Next I added the same lines in ~/.bashrc but not as SU and this did my job pretty well.

Now I need the software to be accessible to other users as well. How do I do it.
Which file must be editted ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, /etc/profile and should I do it as SU?

Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Just add your PATH to `/etc/profile` or if you prefer create a .sh in `/etc/profile.d/` with you path and it will be added to all users upon login.

Comment: I created a new file and put the above lines inside it. However it is still not working. Do I need to do anything else? Like source?

Comment: Yes. You should source the /etc/profile.d/ directory on your /etc/profile

Answer (score 0):

you can add your PATH definition to the `/etc/environment`.