# remove corruption of a command reference in bash

Tags: bash, centos, terminal, docker

> **How do I un-corrupt a command reference in bash?**

On a CentOS 7 server, I am installing Docker and Docker Machine.  The installation has required some manual re-setting of BIOS options and then rebooting the operating system during the installation process.  At first, the `docker-machine` command was found by bash.  But it seems that some of bash's references have been broken during the reboots.  As a result, the commands below for installing Docker Machine and checking its version now result in a failure message, even when I repeatedly run the install command below.

I am following the instructions for setting up Docker Machine [at this link](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/#install-machine-directly).

Here is the terminal output after the final reboot:

```
[root@localhost ~]# base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.14.0 &&  
>   curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/tmp/docker-machine &&  
>   sudo install /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current  
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed  
100   617    0   617    0     0    836      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   836
100 26.7M  100 26.7M    0     0  3481k      0  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:-- 5962k
[root@localhost ~]# docker-machine version
-bash: docker-machine: command not found
[root@localhost ~]#
```

> **Is there some command that I can use to clean all of bash's references so that a clean install can either throw a meaningful error, or hopefully work?  Or are there some diagnostic commands that someone can suggest?**

I am hoping for a more graceful solution than resorting to re-installing the host operating system and reprovisioning everything in the machine from scratch.

---

**User suggestions:**

---

Per @MichaelHomer's suggestion, I tried the following:

```
[root@localhost ~]# PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Per @roaima's suggestion, I tried:

```
[root@localhost ~]# hash -r
[root@localhost ~]# ls -ld /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 28034848 Apr 16 16:18 /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
[root@localhost ~]# echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/bin:/root/bin
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Per @arcsin's suggestion, I typed:

```
[root@localhost ~]# file /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
/usr/local/bin/docker-machine: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
[root@localhost ~]# /usr/local/bin/docker-machine version
docker-machine version 0.14.0, build 89b8332
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`?

Comment: `hash -r` should help. If not please `ls -ld /usr/local/bin/docker-machine` and `echo "$PATH"`

Comment: @roaima Thank you.  Please see the results added to the end of the OP.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Thank you.  Please see the results added to the end of the OP.

Comment: What is the output of `file /usr/local/bin/docker-machine`?  Also, can you run it by giving the full path?  `/usr/local/bin/docker-machine version`?

Comment: @arcsin Please see new edit at end of OP with both your results.  You may need to refresh your browser to see both as I made two separate edits.  You may be onto something.

Comment: @CodeMed the `hash -r` is supposed to fix it... You used that command, but never really called `docker-machine` directly after using that... Try that.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger That solved the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: @roaima It seems that you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons of efficiency, `bash` maintains a list of the directories in the `$PATH` where it found each command.

If you run a command that it couldn't find and then add it, you need to tell `bash` to invalidate its list.

```
hash -r
```

Comment: I puttied into the headless CentOS 7 server again today, and now the `docker-machine` command is giving the same `command not found` error described in the OP.  But I am able to run the program when I type `/usr/local/bin/docker-machine`.  I typed `hash -r` again this morning, and then typed `hash`, which returned a `hash table empty` message.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Sounds like you've not got `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`.

Comment: `echo "$PATH"` prints out `/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/bin:/root/bin`

Comment: Yep: there's no `/usr/local/bin`. To make that a permanent change edit one of `.profile` `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, find the line that starts `PATH=` and append `/usr/local/bin` in the colon-separated list.

Comment: I googled all 3 files .`profile`,.`bash_profile`, and.`bashrc`.  They all seem to be a little different.  Also, some documentation says some of these files are specific to each user.  I want to set a system-wide setting for all users.  Can you be more specific about the steps that should be taken in CentOS 7?

Comment: See [How to set path for all users on CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409126/100397)

Comment: To accomplish what you said, I had to instead use <a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104727/add-a-path-in-path-globally-for-every-user">this link</a> and <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642924/after-changing-etc-profile-what-do-i-have-to-do-to-reset-my-shell">this other link.</a>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76176/discussion-between-roaima-and-codemed).